# How to extract bold content using jsoup from various html pages of different types of bold html expression?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, css-selectors, jsoup

I want to know how to extract bold content from a variety of different html pages and its not necessary that all html pages use , lets say "b" tag or "font-weight: bold" .
I want to know if there is any generic way to look for bold content or is there an exhaustive list of bold html expressions. Similarly I want to look for the same when it comes to content size.

My draft code is below, just in case if some interested

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File input = new File("");
    //String headingcriteria="font[style*=font-weight:bold]";
    String headingcriteria = "b";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
    doc.select("table").remove();
    Elements boldlist = doc.select("*");
    int elementno=1;
    for (Element bold: boldlist){
        try{
            System.out.println("No: "+elementno+"    :::   Content tagname: "+bold.tagName()+"    :::   Content Size: "+
                    getElementContentSize(bold.attr("style")));
        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            System.out.println("No: "+elementno+"    :::   Content tagname: "+bold.tagName()+"    :::   Content Size: NANA");
        }
            elementno+=1;
    }
}
public static String getElementContentSize(String attribs){
    String temp=attribs.split("font-size:")[1];
    return temp.substring(0,temp.indexOf("pt"));

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

To search through style tags:

```
Elements divTags = doc.getElementsByTag("div");

for (Element div : divTags) {
    if (div.attr("style").equals("font-family:'Segoe UI',Arial,sans-serif")) {
        System.out.println(div.text());
    }
}
```

To search through b bold tags:

```
Elements boldTags = doc.getElementsByTag("b");

for (Element tag : boldTags) {
    System.out.println(tag.text());
}
```

To search through strong bold tags:

```
Elements strongTags = doc.getElementsByTag("strong");

for (Element tag : strongTags) {
    System.out.println(tag.text());
}
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Are these the only three ways to express bold content, or are there more ways of expressing them. My qusetion is more of understanding the exhaustive ways a bold content can be expressed in html (of which you expressed three different ways above) , so that I can write a logic to incorporate all those ways.

Comment: I don't know of any other methods for HTML although my knowledge is rather limited. It may also be styled through CSS.